# How to calculate the total link cost between two nodes that are not neighbors?

Tags: netlogo

I have a network where each link has a cost that is calculated as follows:

```
ask links [ set link-cost sum [node-cost] of both-ends ]
```

How can I calculate the total link cost (sum of link cost) between two nodes that are not neighbors ?

```
to total-link-node [ a b ] ;; where a and b are nodes
ask a [ 
 print [link-cost] of (link-with b) ]
end 

gives "OF expected input to be a link agentset or link but got NOBODY instead"
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you'll need https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension for this. Hopefully someone who knows better than I do will answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution by using `nw:path-to` in the Extension NW as suggested by Seth (you can also used `nw:weighted-path-to`) :

```
to total-link-node [a b]
 ask a [ 
  show nw:path-to b 
  print sum (map [ [link-cost] of ? ] nw:path-to b) ]
end
```